# how can I categorize the transactions based on the method they call to transfer and non-transfer transactions using web3?

Tags: transactions, explorers, filters, bscscan, method

Blockchain explorers show "transfer" instead of the method id for some of the transactions on their list, so there should be a way to filter transactions based on the method they call.
How can I filter transaction based on being transfer/non-transfer ones?
I guess I can use

```
web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionSignature
```

Not sure how it can be done though.

I am aware that `debug.traceTransaction` is a possibility, however I'm looking for a less costly way to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function identifier is what will allow you to define transfer vs non transfer function.

Basically, it is the first 4 bytes of the call data.

Take [this transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x87f86d88cc3461b0ed120979bc7c1c47fd3dd8638cc3a4632f02ace629920678) which did a USDC transfer.

The first 4 bytes of the call data are : 0xa9059cbb. Those are matching the first 4 bytes of `keccak256("transfer(address, uint256)")` : 0xa9059cbb....

So you can identify every transfer transaction if the first 4 bytes of call data match that value.

The following code does exactly this on the tx that I linked previously :

```
import web3 from "web3";

const Web3 = new web3("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/PROJECT-ID");

const transferIdentifier = Web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionSignature("transfer(address,uint256)");

const tx = await Web3.eth.getTransaction("0x87f86d88cc3461b0ed120979bc7c1c47fd3dd8638cc3a4632f02ace629920678");

if (tx.input.slice(0, transferIdentifier.length) === transferIdentifier) {
  console.log("This is a transfer");
}
```

Hope that helps !

**EDIT**: [This](https://github.com/ethereum-lists/4bytes) might be usefull for you if you want to identify a wider range of calls.